# How to connect remote mysql from localhost server using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

connect remote mysql to localhost

```
How to connect remote mysql from localhost mysql
```

I need to connect the remote database to my local database . How can I do. Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

1) Go to cPanel and search for Remote Database.

2) Add an access
    Host

3) Put ip you would like to give access

4) Click on `"Add Host"`